# Why wasn't this a helpful edit?

Tags: discussion

I edited [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40079429/1102945) about PDO and [my edit was rejected](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/14195433). I want to understand why my edit wasn't seen as helpful.

The main reason I tried to edit the post was that it came across as very rude. The question asker didn't realize there was a better way to do what they were trying to do. Instead of simply telling the asker about a better method, they said "PDO users are so obsessed with running a *regular SQL* query some tricky way, instead of just running it". I replaced this with a simple statement that they could do it a better way.

I also added more information from the comments, and removed the last paragraph which was another rude jab at the asker ("your class suffer [sic] from many design flaws" ... "many other issues that, I am sure, exist in the rest of your class").

So yes, this changed the original meaning somewhat, but I believed it was a helpful change. Why wasn't it seen that way by the reviewers?

Comment: If you think you can answer the question in a better way, add an answer, don't completely change someone else's.

Comment: Even when salvaging an answer with rude content, you shouldn't replace the OP's words with your own. You should only make the bare minimum changes required to maintain proper grammar. You cut way more than necessary and added more than you should have.

Comment: You edited the rude out of Col Shrapnel's post and didn't come away with any missing body parts?  You're a lucky man.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The answer wasn't being rude at all.  In addition to answering the question asked, it *constructively* noted various other problems and described how they could be addressed.  You were removing valuable information from the post.

The answer was somewhat *terse*, sure, and it was very dry and technical, rather than spending lots of time trying to dance around the problems he's trying to point out to make them not seem like serious problems.  That doesn't make it rude.  Blunt, maybe.  On this site we want people to be specific, right to the point, to have a high signal to noise ratio, and not water down posts with lots of fluff.

Comment: Nobody asked for tutoring (good thing because that's off-topic), so technically speaking the recommendations in the answer were fluff. But to remove them after the fact... well I wouldn't. If YCS stands behind it then community voting on the answer should be enough.

Comment: @Gimby It wasn't noise.  It was tangential to the topic, but related.  It has always been appropriate to include additional information related to the answer that's not strictly necessary for answering the question.  To delete such content (in someone else's answer) is not acceptable behavior in an edit